# How to set up Parallel Redundancy Protocol on linux?

Tags: linux-networking, redundancy, iproute2

I'm trying to setup a PRP connection between to Linux machines (Ubuntu 20-04 LTS) following [the doc from TI](https://software-dl.ti.com/processor-sdk-linux/esd/docs/06_03_00_106/linux/Industrial_Protocols_HSR_PRP.html).

The module `hsr` is present (`modprobe hsr` works), but when I tried to use `iproute2`, it seems that it was compiled without support of HSR/PRP.

```
$ ip link add name prp0 type prp slave1 eth1 slave2 eth2 supervision 45
Garbage instead of arguments "slave1 ...". Try "ip link help"

$ ip link add name prp0 type prp
Error: unknown device type
```

Any ideas how to set up a PRP interface?

Answer (score 1):

`type prp` is not consistent with [`man ip link`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-link.8.html).  iproute documents PRP as `type hsr` but with  `proto 1`. See also the [implementing code commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/commit/?id=68f027724b5fa0854b63d3346a38cb9c62fe1493).

Not that it matters, but possible reasons for the inaccuracy are the guide's commands not being tested, or they were working off a patched iproute that was not the same as what was released.